# Ramadan and Masturbations

Tags: sawm, ramadan, masturbation

Salaamu Alaikum,when one masturbates but doesn't release sperm,then he falls asleep and then in the process he released,and he immediately noticed ,does this invalidate his fast

Answer (score 0):

1st of all you have to know the The propose of fasting is stay away from all the bad unhealthy and unethical acts.
Fight with your nafs.
Masturbation during the holy ramadan renders your fast invalid.
So a irani leader said :
"if he or she do not indent masturbation and discharged semen  and nothing is discharge than fasting is correct even though he/she has done haram act".